# php - htaccess block php files except root files

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have following htaccess code in order to block all .php files.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .*\.php$ 404.php [L]
```

but how i can block only files not in root.

example

```
mywebsite/index.php    -  don't want to block
mywebsite/go/go.php    -  want to block
mywebsite/en/en.php    -  want to block
```

Comment: Don't do it this way. Put the "do not touch" files somewhere outside of your document root. PHP won't care where they are, as long as they're reachable via include_path search or direct path specifications

Comment: lol....i got same problem i am able to catching up include files....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that isn't looping, but you want to change your matching regular expression to include at least 1 depth in your path:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/.*\.php$ 404.php [L]
```

Also, see Marc B's comment.